# Views to show user referenced to node

Tags: 7, views, users

I'm trying to show user info in node where this user name is set in User reference field.

I have content type where is User reference field (field_customer).

I have Views:

- **Show:** Users
- **Contextual filter:** (field_customer) Content: Customer
- **Relationship:** User: Customer (field_customer) - reverse

In Contextual Filter I have: When the filter value is NOT available = Provide default value User ID from URL
In Relationship I have: Require this relationship

And I have fields like User: Email, User: Name etc.

I created node and set one user to User reference field.

Views does not work as it should. It shows all users. I tryed to play with Views settings but just could not find proper settings.

What I am doing wrong here?

***EDIT***

I also created another Views.

- **Show:** Content
- **Contextual Filter:** Content: Customer
- **Relationships:** Content: Customer

In Contextual Filter I have: When the filter value is NOT available Hide view
In Relationships I have: Require this relationship

And it shows nothing on node page. Also tryed with different settings but no luck.

Comment: Just to clarify, is your "user reference" field actually an [entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field that references users?

Comment: It is User reference field type, not Entity reference field. It should be Entity?

Comment: If it's not too late to change your fields, I would strongly recommend moving over to Entity Reference. It should allow a backwards relationship in Views so you can easily get "entities referencing users" :-)

Comment: I just made Entity reference field to reference user and modified my views but still not working. This is odd.

Comment: It sounds like your filters are wrong.  If you're displaying this on a node page, and you've set the View up to get the User ID from the URL, you'll actually be passing the NID into the view as the UID.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of any more help right now - don't have a Sandbox to hand to run this through :(

Comment: If I set Contextual filter When the filter value is NOT available = Display all results for the specified field. Then it shows all users. And when I set it to Hide view then it shows nothing.

Comment: Any help with this? I have tryed to make this work for a hole day..

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to reference the relationship you created down in the filter criteria. 
In the example below I have a views where I want to display all documents of the current logged in user.

1. I created the views showing all documents first. Get your view working the way you want it too first.
2. Create the relationship - I want documents that are related to who authored them
3. Filter your view by the author relationship. So in the example below my view is filtered by the current user - and it shows all documents in which the current user is the author.
4. Once your view is sorted you can work out the user reference part.

Hope this helps

[image: Documents View]